# Spring security test with MockMvc, MockHttpServletRequestBuilder::with user over https

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have problem with https in spring test.

In my application I use custom class that implements `UserDetails`, because of that when I use annotation `@WithMockUser` the result is cast exception:

`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to class my.custom.implemtantion.MyCustomUserDetailsUser.class`

so to deal with it I'm forced to use *MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.with()* method:

```
mockMvc.perform(get(API_URL)
                .with(user(myCustomUserDetailsUser)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

it all work fine, before I add https to security configuration. Now where I use with I get 500

I know that when use `MockMvc` I need create bean and set the `.defaultRequest(METHOD("/").secure(true))`
but how deal with `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder::with`?
Is there something like that in `MockMvc`?
Or maybe there is something like `MockHttp**s**ServletRequestBuilder::with`?

@edit

Then main problem is when I use bean for test:

```
 @Bean
    public MockMvc mockMvc(WebApplicationContext context) {
        return MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .defaultRequest(get("/").secure(true))
                .build();
    }
```

the tests where i use `.with(user(myCustomUserDetailsUser)))` fail with response 500 (principals are null)

When I delete bean and set:
`mockMvc.perform(get(API_URL).secure(true).with(user(myCustomUserDetailsUser))`
all work fine.
But I don't wonna set for all (100+) tests `.secure(true)`

Comment: Have you tried `mockMvc.perform(get(API_URL).secure(true).with(user(myCustomUserDetailsUser))`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. The only thing to change would be the URL everything else would be the same. MockMVc actually doesn't care about http/https at all as it will run a mocked environment not a real one. So not sure what you are attempting to test with MockMvc actually.

Comment: @M.Deinum if you dont declare in MockMvcBuilders 
`.defaultRequest(get("/").secure(true))` 
the return will be 305 when https is required in aplication

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, yes it work. But when I also have a bean MockMvc with 
`.defaultRequest(get("/").secure(true))` the response is 500. I have over 100+. If i delete MockMvc bean I will need to edit my whole test and set secure to true manual in each test

Comment: The main problem is that you declare a bean, which basically destroys Spring Boots ability to provide one preconfigured for you. What you should do is register a `MockMvcConfigurer` which adapts the builder with a default request including the secure and user flag.

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem with adding MockMvcConfigurer to MockMvcBuilders. Now the bean looks like this:

```
 @Bean
    public MockMvc mockMvc(WebApplicationContext context) {
        return MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .defaultRequest(get("/").secure(true))
                .defaultRequest(post("/").secure(true))
                .defaultRequest(put("/").secure(true))
                .build();
    }
```

Where `springSecurituty()` came from`org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;` and return `new SecurityMockMvcConfigurer()`

Thanks to M. Deinum to give me the hint about MockMvcConfigurer.